# why MYSQL limit syntactic is opposite of overloading function in programming language?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit, overloading

```
function limit($count,$offset = 0)
{

}
```

here limit(3); // will work for $offset would get its default value of 0

when we have specific offset value we can do limit(3,10);

but MYSQL limit syntax does opposite it take  limit 3 // which is in align with limit(3)
but when want to use not default value for offset then we have to do in opposite order
limit 10 , 3;
where 10 is offset and 3

Comment: I think you need to put in your SQL to clarify your doubts before more down-vote coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply because the designers designed it to be that way. Sounds like a bad answer, but I don't know how one could answer it better.

Comment: my variant was "it's just fate", but it's too short.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 3 OFFSET 10
```

Why not use this syntax?

Comment: **YES** this is the correct behavior. Although I prefer the shortcut method.